When reading hexadecimal data using python with baudrate 100, receiving only zeros
I am trying to read serial[hexadecimal] data using Python, but when read its showing only zeros.
I tried cross checking the data using a logic analyzer and there i can see the data properly.
If any one can give any solution it will be great.
Pasted below is the code.
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM5',       
    baudrate=100,      # Set baud rate to 100
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    #timeout=1          # Optional: set a timeout for read operations
)

data = ser.read(100)  # Read up to 100 bytes
print(data)`

**Output: **
b'\\xfc\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'

Also i cross checked the port setting with the logic anlayzer, its all same but still not able to see the data.

What are you connecting to?  100 is not a standard baud rate.  Even the original Teletype machines used 110 baud.  11 bits per symbol, 10 characters per second.

If you used a logic analyzer you must have timing, did the timing match the baud rate you expected?

Hi Tim Roberts, Its for a Air conditioner indoor unit board.Yes its a non standard baudarte and its too low. But with the help of a HW engineer i figured out the issue, the USB to Serial cable what i was using will support the baudrate starting form 300 only.Thank you for trying to help.

Hi Mark Ransome, Sorry i did not checked the timinmgs , the Logic Analyzer is having an inbuild Protocoal analyzer, so i used that to decode and see the values. But i figured out the issue and commented in to Tim Roberts reply. Thank you for trying to help.

for some one else who is finding the solution, i figured out the issue. I was using a USB to serial cable and the chip used in that will support only from 300 baudrate.
Thank you all for trying to help me.
This post can be closed.

Thank you for sharing the solution. No need to close the question, you can just "accept" your own answer so everyone knows the solution. Click the ✅
